# PHP LIKE QUERY return 0 data

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

i have a table called `products` and with products table have many records on products columns the column Size have data but my php `like` query returns 0 record please resolve my problem if you know.

the value in Size column:

```
05-2250,13.0cm;05-2252,14.0cm;05-2254,15.0cm;05-2256,17.5cm;05-2258,20.0cm;

$prdrs=mysql_query("Select * from products where pID LIKE '%05-2254%' OR name LIKE '%05-2254%' OR Art LIKE '%05-2254' OR exArt LIKE '%05-2254' OR smallDesc LIKE '%05-2254%'  OR  Color LIKE '%05-2254' OR  Size LIKE '%05-2254%' AND enable='$enable' ORDER BY pID ASC")or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($prdrs)>0){
echo "Yes";
}else{
echo "No";
}
```

result: No
if i run this command on phpmyadmin 2 result shown but in my php page result is 0 record

anyone have solution please i need this

Comment: I think you need to rethink your database design. This feels just not right. If you have products and product descriptions in different tables, you might be making your life dificult. Unless this is just a lookup table. As to answer your question: Don't use like; You want an exact match: select * from products where pname=$search or size=$search

Comment: Have you tried running your query through PHPMyAdmin with a specific search string? Or echo the query you got in the end? We don't know the data in your tables to know if that represents a problem, but if you do some tests you will understand the problem better.

Comment: Your query is syntactically correct . Considering the values in `Size` column , your query should return a row . The problem might be somewhere else . However did you run the query in PHPMyAdmin ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe really your code is performing a

Select * from products where pname LIKE '%-2247%' OR Size LIKE '%-2247%' (the result of 5 - 2252) ?